# What is the origin of oak leaves in military insignia and decorations?

Tags: military

Several military insignia and decorations use an "oak leaf" motif:

- Majors and Lieutenant Commanders in the US Armed Forces have a [single stylized gold oak leaf](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:US-O4_insignia.svg) insignia.
- Lieutenant Colonels and Commanders get the same thing in [silver](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:US-O5_insignia.svg).
- Senior officers in the US and British armed forces get [oak leaves on the visors of their caps](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/US_Navy_Hat_Commander_Scrambled_Eggs.jpg) ("scrambled eggs").
- [Oak leaf](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/Queen%27s_Commendation_for_Valuable_Service.png) and [oak leaf cluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oak_leaf_cluster) ribbon devices are used as decorations or as decoration "add-ons" in several cases, e.g. as the symbol for "mentioned in despatches" and for the King's Commendation for Valuable service in the UK, to indicate multiple awards of a medal in the US, and to distinguish the [Bundeswehr Cross of Honour for Valour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundeswehr_Cross_of_Honour_for_Valour) from the Gold Cross of Honour.

I know that the use in insignia dates back to at least the US Civil War, and in decorations at least to [their addition to Pour le Mérite in 1813](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pour_le_M%C3%A9rite#Military_class), but I'm not sure if it goes beyond that.

Is there a common origin for these? Which came first? Why oak leaves in particular?

Comment: Oak leaves were a.o. used by the Romans to signify bravery: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civic_Crown

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo The *Iron Cross* had oak leaves long before WWII, which it got about contemporaneous to *Pour le Mérite*. Neither was even *close* to being the first military insignia to have them (see Jos' comment).

Comment: Oak was attributed to thunder / lightning deities in many cultures (Greek, Norse, Celtic, Baltic, and Slavic). The Hebrew mythology features oak trees several times. It is (one of) the hardest woods available in Europe, the wood you would craft spear shafts from, and from there to an overall symbol of strength and fortitude isn't that much of a stretch.

Comment: I did a quick google search and there are _multiple_ opinions, but nothing I can find that is authoriative.

Comment: I think Devsolar has the right of it - oak is the plant equivalent of the lion in European cultures. The king of the trees.

Comment: That all sounds pretty good, but I'd love to see an answer :)

Comment: @hobbs From the time frame I referenced, this will be one of those questions that *actually* asks "what is the oldest *recorded* use", which IMNSHO should *never* be confused with "what is the origin", especially since half of the civilisations I mentioned have a written tradition and the other half haven't. This is mist-of-time type of stuff, and very likely parallel development as well, so I don't quite see how there could be "the" answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

##### Oak leaves signify bravery for millennia

The earliest I could find was Roman: [the Civic crown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Mytilene_(81_BC)) was a coronet of oak leaves, given for saving the life of a fellow citizen in battle. Julius Caesar won one during [the siege of Mytilene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Mytilene_(81_BC)). The Civic Crown ranked second highest, after the [Grass Crown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grass_Crown).

Oaks and their leaves were important for the Celts and later the Germanic tribes as well, culminating ***much later*** in military decorations with oak leaves. The earliest modern military decoration is the [Légion d'honneur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_of_Honour) in 1802. Before that commanders were given noble ranks or knightly decorations, and lower ranks usually a monetary reward. (The grand cross has a laurel and an oak wreath behind the cross.)

The American tradition is merely a continuation of this ancient custom.

Your second question was about the silver/gold insignia difference in the US Army. Wikipedia has a [comprehensive explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Army_officer_rank_insignia#:%7E:text=Silver%20versus%20gold,-In%20terms%20of&text=Infantry%20officers%20wore%20silver%20epaulettes,wore%20epaulettes%20with%20no%20insignia.) on that. In a nutshell: the senior/oldest ranks were silver, and kept it. Junior/newer ranks got gold. Do mind that this is strictly about the US Army. Other armies have different traditions.

Comment: Note that the silver / gold thing can be quite different in other militaries. German Major / Oberstleutnant / Oberst are silver, while Generals are gold.

Comment: @DevSolar You're absolutely correct. The question was about US military, not German or any other military. I'm Dutch, and it works very different there. Not (entirely) German, British or US. With a bit of French thrown in, to make it spicy. Just about most armies have their own traditions.

Comment: @Jos Where in the question is it stated that the question is about the US Armed Forces?

Comment: I don't say your answer is wrong in that regard. I just prefer it when the whole is at least mentioned, because too many people run around believing that the part they know is all there is to it ("junior officers always wear gold!").

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo "Majors and Lieutenant Commanders in the US Armed Forces" (first bullet). I find it difficult to see that as anything else but US Armed forces.

Comment: @Jos Yes, that was one of several bullet points. Also, there are Majors in the British Army and Lieutenant Commanders in the Royal Navy. Since the US is just some 250 years old, why assume that its insignia was developed internally, rather than being imported from Europe? Doesn't *Colonel* come from Italian? One way of restricting focus to a particular country is via the use of country tags. To the best of my knowledge, no country tags were used

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Feel free to write your own answer.

Comment: @Jos Why? Yours is pretty decent

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't actually *asking* about the silver/gold difference, just mentioning it in passing.